# Date data corrupted swift

Tags: swift

Anytime I make an API call, I get a response from my API call. But I always end up with a dataCorrupted error about the date. If I close the app and open it again, I get my result without any issue.

The backend expects a date in this format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` UTC but because I am using a date and time picker, it always seems to exclude the miliseconds. So I improvised.

I simply have a date extension

```
var postableDate: String {
        
        let formatter = DateFormatterPool.backendDateFormatter
            formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

            let millisecondsString = formatter.string(from: self)

            let nanoseconds = DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds % 1_000_000
            let nanosecondsString = String(format: ".%03d", nanoseconds)

            return millisecondsString + ".001" + "Z"
    }
```

I do not know how the response becomes corrupted and closing and reopening the app, I get no issues. Even if I change tabs and my data is fetched again, I still get the error until I close and reopen the app

```
struct Model: Codable {
...
    var departureTime: Date
...
}

func getRequest(with requestID: String) async throws -> BaseResponseData<Model> {
        try await requestFactory.request(
            with: ApiRouter.getRequest(requestID: requestID),
            customDecoder: DateDecoder())
    }
```

Comment: Replace all of your date formatter code by using `ISO8601DateFormatter`.

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" is wrong. You are ignoring the date string timezone. Z means UTC so you should NEVER escape it